# Hibernate InheritanceType.JOINED prevents table creation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, inheritance

I have two classes, "OrderBase" and "OrderPay", for which I am trying to implement an inheritance of type  "InheritanceType.JOINED".

While TABLE_PER_CLASS and SINGLE_TABLE work fine, it cannot be created once I change the Type to "JOINED" and I cannot figure out why.

I dropped and recreated the schema when switching the inheritance type to ensure that is not the issue.

It also happens with any other classes for which I am trying to implement inheritance of that type.

My table creation strategy is "create":
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

When changing it to "update", the error will still persist, even though the table exists in the database (before and after the error is thrown).

I also created a new project to ensure nothing else prevents it from functioning and the identical error still occurs.

I shared the project here on github. The specs for the schema creation with mysql on localhost are in the application.properties file:
https://github.com/Danielmethner/brownbag

Here the classes:

1. OrderBase.java

```java
package com.brownbag_api.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_BASE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class OrderBase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3458221490393509305L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private double amount;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

2. OrderPay.java

```java
package com.brownbag_api.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class OrderPay extends OrderBase  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4643589803146964779L;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "BOOK_TEXT")
    private String bookText;

    public OrderPay() {
    }

    public String getBookText() {
        return bookText;
    }

    public void setBookText(String bookText) {
        this.bookText = bookText;
    }
}
```

The stack trace is as follows (effectively boils down to "table of parent class not found")

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table brownbag.order_base not found

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.brownbag</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>API for brownbag project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does OrderPay inherit from correct class? Shouldn't it be OrderBase?

Comment: It was a typo in the post, in the source code it was correct and the error therefore still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Probably you inherit from javax.persistence.criteria.Order.

If you change your OrderPay to extend from correct OrderBase class then everything works as expected and tables are created:

```
public class OrderPay extends OrderBase {

    //rest of code

}
```

Additionally, get rid of this property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=brownbag
```

You already define the database to connect to in spring.datasource.url.

Comment: Sorry the typo was only in the answer, the actual source code is correct and the error persists

Comment: Can you edit your question so it contains real code with imports?

Comment: I added the imports. However, I tried implementing this type of inheritance in any other class of this project and it wont work anywhere.

Comment: Which version of hibernate (or spring-data-jpa) are you using? Can you paste or pom.xml and application.properties as well?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the version is managed, based on Spring Boot Version "2.2.6.RELEASE"
I also pasted a GitHub link with the project. Many thanks! :)